# AzureBlobStorage fails when enumerating Pageable<BlobContainerItem> result from GetBlobContainers with RequestFailedException, not authorized

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I am building an infrastructure wrapper around Azure Blob Storage for a shared component in a .Net Core 6 suite of applications, both web and desktop-based applications. I’m using version 12.14.1 of Azure.Storage.Blobs.

```
public BlobContainerItem[] GetContainers(string sasToken)
{
 blobUri = "https://spiffyaccountname.blob.core.windows.net?" + sasToken;

 var client = new BlobServiceClient(blobUri);
 var containers = client.GetBlobContainers(); // Succeeds!
 var array = containers.array()               // Fails with Azure.RequestFailedException
 return array;
}
```

Exception Details:

```
Azure.RequestFailedException: This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.
RequestId:...
Time:...
Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this resource type.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationResourceTypeMismatch
```

I don't think it's a code issue but rather a configuration issue, as creating and deleting containers work fine, though I haven't been able to find the setting to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the reason you are getting this error is because of incorrect permissions in your SAS token.

Please check for 2 things:

1. **Use Account SAS** - Listing containers require that you use [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) instead of [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas).
2. **Use proper permissions** - Listing containers require that your account SAS has `SignedServices` as `Blob` (`ss=b`), `SignedResourceTypes` as `Service` (`srt=s`) and `SignedPermission` should have at least `List` permission (`sp=l`).